Cannot connect to home server via SSH on Arch Linux
I was trying to install Arch Linux on my home server but SSH cannot connect to host saying: ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.103 port 22: Connection timed out, also SSH cannot resolve archiso.local.
I used this article on Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_via_SSH
My server has internet connection because I can ping router and sites.
My computer and server locates on single wifi. Computer connected via Ethernet and server uses usb wifi. Computer running on Windows 11.

I fixed the issue by plugging ethernet cable and it just works. Archiso don't have firewall installed and router's all isolations are disabled.

Did you check your router for any configuration like client/AP isolation? They are often set ON for wifi/cable devices, so devices from the Wifi cannot access the cable ones.
Also, I would go full cable before enabling the server to use an USB wifi card. Is this a possibility?

I didn't check because I'm renting WiFi from my provider and I don't have access to It's settings. Seems like laying cable is the only correct solution
